# Configurable product

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm playing with custom module shoppingcart.
I currently have a product part with fields price and sku. What would be the best way to add a configurable product for example a shirt has different colors and sizes. But now all products has to be configurable. I want to have the user select from a dropdown in my view from available sizes.

If I create a new content part and attach enumeration field to i must choose one item when i create product from backend. What I want is to render all the items in the enumeration field in the view and be able to select one.

// Tomas

Comment: I don't know that specific module, but that information will have to be attached to the shopping cart line item, not to the product, so an enumeration field is not going to cut it, you're going to have to implement that yourself entirely.